# Table row with subrows

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to create a sub row for the last row in the table to look like in the photo, I have tried to do it with the span, but the row height won't change so I am a bit stuck here.

```
<tr>
    <td class="semi-bold">2017</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Montant principal : 700,00<br>
                                            Pénalité : 0<br>
                                            Majoration de retard : 100</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Peugeot</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">000000B1</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">8 CV</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">800,00</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">
    <span class="state">
     <i class="state-suspended"></i>Rejeté
    </span>
    <span class="position-absolute bottom-0 start-0"><hr/>Motif de rejet : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: As displayed in the image, don't we have a gray-bordered div containing a table of 7 cols followed by a div with a top border?

Comment: @Dfaure not necessarily. You could also add a border simply to the 2nd tr while using rowspan on it.

Comment: Anyway, this involve more than a single row...

Comment: @tacoshy or is there a way to do it without involving tr ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. Count how many `<td/>` (columns) your table has. I count 7 but I may be wrong.
2. Get rid of the `<span/>` elements you have added, and close the `</tr>` normally.
3. Create a new `<tr>` (a new row).
4. Place a single `<td>` (a cell) into the new row, giving it the attribute `colspan=7`. That stands for "column span". It means the cell will extend through all 7 columns.
5. Place your text inside the new `<td>`.

---

```
<tr>
    <td class="semi-bold">2017</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Montant principal : 700,00<br>
                                            Pénalité : 0<br>
                                            Majoration de retard : 100</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">Peugeot</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">000000B1</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">8 CV</td>
    <td class="semi-bold">800,00</td>
    <td class="semi-bold"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <hr/>
    <td colspan="7">Motif de rejet : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</td>
</tr>
```

It should be exactly what you want.

---

Further reading – [Table Rowspan And Colspan In HTML Explained (With Examples)](https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/)

Comment: the span is inside a td element... `<td class="semi-bold">
    <span class="state">
     <i class="state-suspended"></i>Rejeté
    </span>
    <span class="position-absolute bottom-0 start-0"><hr/>Motif de rejet : Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.</span>
    </td>`

Comment: @tacoshy: my bad, thanks for pointing it out. I updated my answer.

Comment: what about the border-top ?

Comment: @Thomas Bonini what if i want to add it as a span for the the row, and not dedicate a new row just for that ?

Comment: you cant which would be an invalid markup. The only other legitimate method would be to create a pseudo-element with `::after`